# In pandas, I get an error when the data frame replace function doesn't find the value to be replaced. How do I handle this?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, data-wrangling

My code has the below line:

```
df.replace({'SCORE':{'N.A.':np.nan}})
```

I am trying to replace all occurrences of 'N. A.' in the column 'SCORE' with Nan. This works for me as long as the column has at least 1 N. A. If no N. A. is present, I get an error. I've looked at the pandas documentation and all over SO and Google. Could someone please tell me how to make the replace function ignore if there is no issue with the data? Thanks.

Comment: try surrounding it with a try-except and passing through the except block

Comment: Works fine for me even without any 'N.A.' present: `df = pd.DataFrame({'SCORE':[1,2,3]}); df.replace({'SCORE':{'N.A.':np.nan}})`

Comment: Please edit your post to include a reproducible example -- a small dataframe that will produce this error (and the full error traceback you're getting).

Comment: What is your pandas version? It does not produce an error on version 0.25.3. Maybe you are using an older version? You can try updating pandas to solve the issue without a hassle.

Comment: @tdy: interesting. When I run the dummy example in your comment, I get the same problem as the original one.       (TypeError : cannot compare types ndarray(dtype=int64) and str) my pandas version is 0.20.1

Comment: @thilina: I unfortunately can't upgrade as it is a work computer

Comment: @vedank: I could do a whole try-except, but I'd expect that if there was nothing to replace, pandas wouldn't give me an issue. So trying to understand this behavior

Comment: I would suggest following @tdy's suggestion of showing us an input dataframe that reproduces the error

Comment: @dim.darkasian: Then you can use try-except as suggested by Vedank or use the 'if' condition as I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if 'N.A.'s exist in 'SCORE' before trying to replace them.

```
if 'N.A.' in df.SCORE:
    df.SCORE.replace('N.A.', np.nan, inplace=True)
```